# Why is an *ngFor loop breaking my sidebar animation in Internet Explorer?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, animation, angular-animations

I have an animation which works well in Chrome but not in IE. I expect to slide a panel in from outside the browser window into view and then once the exit button or `<div>` which covers the rest of the page is clicked, the panel will animate off the screen and out of view. However, the actual result is that **the whole page is transformed and not the specific element.**

View demonstrations below:

**Chrome (works fine; animation is smooth):**
[image: Chrome Demonstration]

**IE (bug; entire page is moved):**
[image: IE Demonstration]

**EDIT**

So I have found the reason why this is happening and it is because of an `*ngFor` when rendering HTML inside of the `container`.  If I remove the `ngFor` completely and all other property bindings, the animation runs as expected (as demonstrated in the Chrome GIF).

I didn't add this code to the question initially because I wouldn't have thought that some `*ngFor` logic would break the CSS.

So my question is, why is the `*ngFor` breaking the animation and how do I fix it?

**Code:**

*side-bar-component.ts:*

```
animations: [
    trigger('animateInOutTrigger', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }),
        animate('0.3s', style({ transform: 'translateX(-100%)' }))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate('0.3s', style({ transform: 'translateX(0%)' }))
      ])
    ]),
    trigger('fadeScrim', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ transform: 'opacity: 0' }),
        animate('0.3s', style({ opacity: '1' }))
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate('0.3s', style({ opacity: '0' }))
      ]),
    ]),
```

*side-bar-component.html*:

```
<div id="btn-scrim" *ngIf="windowWidth >= 768 && open" class="scrim" (click)="onCloseSideBar()" @fadeScrim></div>
<div *ngIf="windowWidth >= 768 && open" class="sidebar-wrapper">
  <div @animateInOutTrigger class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <span class="text">Claim Details</span>
      <span id="btn-close-sidebar-desktop" (click)="onCloseSideBar()">X</span>
    </div>
    <div class="claims claims-padding">
        <hr-claim-detail [id]="'claim-scroller-' + element.claim_id" *ngFor="let element of group.data" [element]="element (update)="updateAndClose()" [windowWidth]="windowWidth" [token]="token [logConfig]="logConfig">
        </hr-claim-detail>
  </div>
</div>
```

*side-bar-component.scss*:

```
.sidebar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  z-index: 2;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 16px 24px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.scrim {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .32);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.header {
  height: 56px;
  background-color: #333333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 24px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.text {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.claims {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 1;
}

.claims-padding {
  padding-bottom: 25vh;
}
```

**STACKBLITZ RECREATION**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ven7eu

I've tried:

- Using `state` to control the transition instead of using `:enter` and `:leave`
- Performing the same functionality without the Angular animations library and purely with CSS conditional classes

Other information:

- Angular Core 8.0.0
- Angular Animations 8.0.0 (I've tried downgrading to older versions and upgrading to latest minor and patch versions)

Comment: I tested on my side with your code in stackblitz. The result in IE is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f68Vq.gif. And it's the same in Edge. I think the animation of the panel works well. Do you mean the `<span>` and `<article>` will move a little when the panel comes out and in?

Comment: @YuZhou Yes the stackblitz animation does work well in IE/Edge which believes me to think that there is a problem with my code. I think it could be a FPS issue. I will investigate further.

Comment: 30/07/19 - Question updated; comments above are irrelevant.

Comment: I made a demo using the code you provided, but I couldn't reproduce the issue. The page is blank: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-frkm7r. Is there anything you miss in the code snippet?

Comment: Yes @YuZhou you are right, there was some missing code which I have now added to the question and also a new Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ven7eu. Strangely, the animations aren't triggering correctly, I'll investigate further.

Comment: Animations fixed. @YuZhou Forgot to add the animations package to the app.module file!

Comment: It's so strange that the sample you provide works well in all browsers. You could use F12 dev tools to compare the CSS style in different browser. Check if there're some different styles applied between Chrome and IE.

Comment: @YuZhou Problem has been found but now just needs a solution, I've updated the question again!

Comment: 01/08/19 - Question updated; comments above are irrelevant

Comment: why aren't we using fixed position for `sidebar-wrapper`?

Comment: @MunimMunna Because the height of the ```sidebar-wapper``` will be relative to the browser window and not the enclosing div.

Comment: @MunimMunna Having said that, position fixed does fix the animation bug.

Comment: @JamesBarrett what is the problem now? Is not so clear, because the reproduction (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ven7eu) works well on IE, Edge, Chrome... I mean it slides RTL and it disappears if I click on backdrop or X. So what is the problem, how can I reproduce it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed by using `fixed` positioning and then programmatically setting the `margin-top` equal to `getBoundingClientRect().top` of the main content container.

I still do not understand why using `absolute` positioning in this scenario won't work.

Comment: IMO, there is a problem in your solution-finding-process. "why" and "Internet explorer" can't fit in the same sentence for your own mind-safety...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try to wrap an [ng-container](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#group-sibling-elements-with-ng-container) around your *ngFor loop? This element has been invented by the Angular team for special cases where you need to loop and create an element several times, but the styling should not be affected by the *ngFor loop.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let element of group.data">
    <hr-claim-detail [id]="'claim-scroller-' + element.claim_id" [element]="element (update)="updateAndClose()" [windowWidth]="windowWidth" [token]="token [logConfig]="logConfig">
    </hr-claim-detail>
</ng-container>
```